# Oracle Virtual Box Host IP Issue

Tags: oracle, virtualbox

I configured 2 guest OS (CentOS & Windows10) in virtual box and the base machine running on windows 10. both guest OS are configured with 2 network cards one is on NAT and other one is Bridged. My problem is only one guest machine is taking IP from my org dhcp and other one is not. please suggest. I tried configuring manual IP but, its not pining.

Comment: Check this explanation here: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat . The NAT configured hosts shouldn't be visible from outside, except if you set a prot forwarding or something. The traffic is sent through the Host Adapter, which actually has a dhcp provided ip address. Btw, any particular reason not to use Bridged Adapter on the second guest?

Answer (score 0):

NAT wont take IP address, it will create internal network and communicate via hosts network IP address.